# Are ontic predicates similarly (or even well) defined across philosophers? Do they differ from logic predicates?

Tags: ontology, terminology, definitions, predicate-logic

I've seen the term "ontic predicate" bandied around in some works. Whenever it has a clear definition it seem no different than how one would define it in (first-order) logic, i.e. it being about a relation. Is there any other definition for "ontic predicate" that is not ambiguous and reasonably widespread?

Comment: I haven't seen this term used other than by Mertz or in discussions of his instance ontology, see e.g. [Two Versions of an Argument for Particularism](http://www.phil.gu.se/posters/festskrift3/svennerlind.pdf):"*According to the doctrine, universals are not ontic predicates; i.e., they lack adicity. It would be more accurate for Mertz to say that universals provide the foundations of the adicities of unit relations.*" Unless we count Heidegger, who had something else in mind.

Comment: This is a paper discussing Heidegger's Being as Ontological Predicate (https://www.jstor.org/stable/43154947?seq=1). "*It's usually assumed Kant denies that "being" is a real or determining predicate, he affirms that it merely is a logical or grammatical one. Now if Heidegger's interpretation was right, there would seem to be misinterpretations..."*

Comment: @Conifold: it surely appeared earlier; e.g. in a [1970s paper](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED066964.pdf) of [Chung-ying Cheng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chung-ying_Cheng). It's also not clear if anyone using it is espousing any Heideggerian ontic vs ontological distinction (probably not).